# How do I scrapy a particular webpage with a login form bearing only a nameless password field, and then submit values to ajax? with Selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Python Scrapy, have this so far:

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['flashfurniture.com']
    start_urls = ['http://flashfurniture.com/']

    skus = ['LE-L-C-BLACK-GG', 'SZ-TUFT-SIL-GG']
    zips = ['33122', '90210', '07501', '60007']
    qtys = [1, 2, 12, 24, 50]

    def start_requests(self):
        for sku in self.skus:
            yield scrapy.Request(url='http://www.flashfurniture.com/'+sku.lower()+'.html', cookies=[{'name': 'password', 'value': 'fubar', 'domain': 'www.flashfurniture.com', 'path': '/'}], callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        sku = response.css('#fobTable .product-code::text').extract_first()
        self.log(sku)
        for zip in self.zips:
            for qty in self.qtys:
                return scrapy.FormRequest(url=response.url, formdata={'vwquantity': str(qty), 'shippingAddressDS.shipping_ROW0_zip': zip}, callback=self.after_post)
                #self.log('LTL FDX')
                #pass #write to file

    def after_post(self, response):
        LTL = response.css('#calcBox .unique-shipment #rateRad0[value]::text').extract_first()
        FDX = response.css('#calcBox .unique-shipment #rateRad1[value]::text').extract_first()
        self.log('LTL $%s FDX $%s' % (LTL, FDX))
        self.log(response.xpath('//div[@class="show-button"][@style]'))
```

The above returns the SKUs (way to go right) and

```
2017-12-18 14:28:51 [example] DEBUG: LTL $None FDX $None
2017-12-18 14:28:51 [example] DEBUG: []
2017-12-18 14:28:51 [example] DEBUG: LTL $None FDX $None
2017-12-18 14:28:51 [example] DEBUG: []
```

The very last line is supposed to be a login success test.

Note that the password included in my above code is invalid; hopefully you can help me figure this out anyway.

What I'm trying to achieve should be pretty clear: I need ultimately to write to CSV five rows per SKU/page parsed, to contain the following:

> *SKU*, Z0Q0L, Z0Q0F, Z1Q0L, Z1Q0F, Z2Q0L, Z2Q0F, Z3Q0L, Z3Q0F 
>   Q1, Z0Q1L, Z0Q1F, Z1Q1L, Z1Q1F, Z2Q1L, Z2Q1F, Z3Q1L, Z3Q1F 
>   Q2, Z0Q2L, Z0Q2F, Z1Q2L, Z1Q2F, Z2Q2L, Z2Q2F, Z3Q2L, Z3Q2F 
>   Q3, Z0Q3L, Z0Q3F, Z1Q3L, Z1Q3F, Z2Q3L, Z2Q3F, Z3Q3L, Z3Q3F 
>   Q4, Z0Q4L, Z0Q4F, Z1Q4L, Z1Q4F, Z2Q4L, Z2Q4F, Z3Q4L, Z3Q4F

where Q*N* = qty[] index representing the value and z0q0l for example = value returned for #rateRad0 (LTL) with 1st zip (33122) and 1st qty (1).

I need to calculate the shipping in each of these combinations for 100+ products, please help. Thank you.

Thinking I should incorporate Selenium but not sure as to how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Write code to save the response body object in HTML format. If your required object is in the downloaded HTML file then check your XPath/CSS selectors, If not it is probably because of AJAX calls, to solve this problem use [SplahRequest](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) instead of scrapy.Request

Comment: Looks like the way to go but how do I get started

Comment: I'm on Windows though and Splash seems to require docker and in the docs here http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html there are no Windows instructions

Comment: You can use this to install docker https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/ , if you are making a big project using scrapy I would suggest I would suggest going for Linux.